# DSL with groovy -> passing values to metaClass methods

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm trying to write a mini DSL for some specific task. For this purpose I've been trying to solve a problem like this below (without using parantheses):

```
give me 5 like romanLetter    
give me 5 like word
```

where the first line would return "V" and the second "five"

My definitions for the first part *give me 5* look like this

```
def give = { clos -> clos() } 
def me = { clos ->  [:].withDefault { it 
                println it} 
         }
```

and then *give me 5* prints 5

The problem is how to add more metaclass methods on the right. E.g.

```
give me 5 like romanLetter -> prints V OR 
give me 5 like word -> prints five
```

my intuition is that I define *like* as

```
Object.metaClass.like = {orth -> if (orth.equals("roman")){ println "V"} 
                                 else {println "five"} }
```

this metaClass method *like* works only if there is a returned value from the left to be applied to, right? I tried adding a return statement in all of the closures which are on the left side but I always receive

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: like 
for class: com.ontotext.paces.rules.FERulesScriptTest ...
```

do you have an idea how shall I do?

========================================

Here is the application of what I'm asking for.
I want to make a rule as follows

```
add FEATURE of X opts A,B,C named Y
```

where *add* is a closure, *of, opts* and *named* are MetaClass methods (at least that's how i imagine it), *X, A, B, C, Y* are parameters most probably strings and *FEATURE* is either a MetaClass property, or a closure without arguments or a closure with arguments.

If *FEATURE* does not take arguments then it is enough that *add* takes *FEATURE* as argument and returns a value on which

Object.metaClass.of will be executed with parameter X

Object.metaClass.opts will be executed on the returned by OF value with parameters A, B, C

Object.metaClass.named will be executed on the returned by opts value with parameter Y

each one of these metaclass methods sets its parameter as a value in a map, which is passed to a JAVA method when *named* is called.

I'm not sure this is the best solution for such a problem, but it seems to me such for the moment. The problem is if FEATURE is not a property itself but a closure which takes argument (e.g. feature1 ARG1). Then

```
add feature1 ARG1 of X opts A,B,C named Y
```

and this is the case which I'm stuck with. *add feature1 ARG1* is the *give me 5* part and I'm trying to add the rest to it.

========================================================

EXAMPLES: 
I need to have both of the following working:

```
add contextFeature "text" of 1,2,3 opts "upperCase" named "TO_UPPER"
add length named "LENGTH"
```

where in the first case by parsing the rule, whenever each metaclass method *of, opts, named* is called I fill in the corresponding value in the following map:

```
params = [feature: "text",
        of: 1,2,3,
        opts: "upperCase",
        named: "TO_UPPER"]
```

ones this map is filled in, which happens when *named* is parsed, I call a java method 
setFeature(params.of, params.named, params.opts, params.feature)

In the second case length is predefined as length = "length", params values will be only

```
params = [feature : length, 
    of: null,
    opts: null,
    named: "LENGTH"]
```

and since of is null another java method will be called which is addSurfaceFeature(params.feature, params.named). The second case is more or less streight forward, but the first one is the one I can't manage.

Thanks in advance! Iv

Comment: This is tricky, as the parser will see that line as: `give( me ).5( like ).romanLetter` so it will try to call `5( like )` on an object returned from `give( me )`.  It's do-able, but are you sure that's the formatting you want?  Something like `number 5 to romanLetter` would probable be easier to code and maintain

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that you should decide on a final DSL spec before starting to code it, as it's not always going to be easy to just add extra functionality at the end

Comment: Nice to hear from you Tim:-)

I've kind of decided. I have the following structure:

`add FEATURE of X opts A,B,C named Y`
where `FEATURE` could be either single method/closure with no parameters or closure with parameter and that's where my problem comes from (X, A, B, C and Y are parameters). The case where it is a closure with parameter is equal to the give me 5 case, the other one I know how to solve.
or

Comment: Hi :)  Can you put examples with the required output into the question?

Comment: just added it to the question under the double line

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but do you have an example with values filled in for both forms, and the required output?  It's hard to see from `add feature1 ARG1 of X opts A,B,C named Y` exactly what you want it to do. (and I think to pass the arg to the FEATURE, you're going to need `add feature1( ARG1 ) of X opts A,B,C named Y` or `add feature1 args ARG1 of X opts A,B,C named Y`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of thing...  Does that get you close?

```
def contextFeature( type ) {
  "FEATURE_$type"
}

// Testing

new IvitaParser().parse {
  a = add text of 1,2,3 opts "upperCase" named "TO_UPPER"
  b = add length named "LENGTH"
  c = add contextFeature( "text" ) of 1,2,3 opts "upperCase" named "TO_UPPER"
}

assert a == [feature:'text', of:[1, 2, 3], opts:'upperCase', named:'TO_UPPER']
assert b == [feature:'length', of:null, opts:null, named:'LENGTH']
assert c == [feature:'FEATURE_text', of:[1, 2, 3], opts:'upperCase', named:'TO_UPPER']

// Implementation

class IvitaParser {
  Map result

  def parse( Closure c ) {
    c.delegate = this
    c.resolveMethod = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    c()
  }

  def propertyMissing( String name ) {
    name
  }

  def add( String param ) {
    result = [ feature:param, of:null, opts:null, named:null ]
    this
  }

  def of( Object... values ) {
    result.of = values
    this
  }

  def named( String name ) {
    result.named = name
    result
  }

  def opts( String opt ) {
    result.opts = opt
    this
  }
}
```

You can even get rid of the quotes on the definition:

```
a = add text of 1,2,3 opts upperCase named TO_UPPER
b = add length named LENGTH
```

As the propertyMissing method just converts unknown properties into a String of their name

Comment: Hi, this covers some of the cases but not the one which is problematic such as: 
`add contextfeature text of 1,2,3 opts upperCase named TO_UPPER`

Comment: the token *contextFeature* could be also *feature* or *conjunction* etc, which shows the type of the feature "text". In my case the feature "text" could be either *contextFeature* or *feature* or *documentFeature*

Comment: @ivita added that case, as I said above, you need to parenthesise this case, or else you would probably need another step.  Starting to wonder whether teaching people the way to create a Groovy Map by hand (ie: type `[feature:'text', of:[1, 2, 3], opts:'upperCase', named:'TO_UPPER']`) would be easier than teaching people the DSL?

Comment: @ivita Don't get me wrong, DSLs have their place, but the idea that you can write a DSL to give to non-programmers and have them use it with no problems or training seems (to me at least) foolish. A GUI which writes DSL code, and allows the user to skip the GUI and just write DSL when they get to know how it works, or teaching the users to program is often a better route ;-)

Comment: @ivita For the complex syntax wanted (i.e. "add feature1 ARG1 of X opts A,B,C named Y") perhaps writing your own little parser in some language could be an option. You wouldn't be constrained by things like commas in "A,B,C" and would have much greater control over all your syntax choices. Are you constrained by your choice of programming language? If not, there's surely many choices on the JVM and other platforms.